# check if multiples values exists in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the foloowing data from an api

```
 obj = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  job      :null
  id       : 5566,
};
```

i want to check if the value is not empty in the `obj` before rendering
I tried

```
render() {
  return (
   <div>
   obj.firstName && <p>{obj.firstName}</p>
   </div>
          );
}
```

it works fine but i will have multiple duplicated code if i'm gonna check every value(firstName/lastName/job etc ...) also i need to put firstName and LastName in one line `<p>{obj.firstName} - {obj.lastName}</p>` how can i make the check in a efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of optional chaining (?.) to make it more efficient and feasible. Even nested objects can be validated  a?.b?.c?.d .
For more info look into this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <p>{obj?.firstName} - {obj?.lastName } </p>
      </div>
      );}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code example if for if your api data is returned as an array. I made the function `isUnd()` that checks if the data is undefined/unincluded in the dataset, if it is it will return an empty string, else return the data.

```jsx
export default function App() {
  const people = [{
    firstName: "Elon",
    lastName: "Musk",
    job: "Tesla CEO",
    id: 1111,
  },{
    firstName: "Leo",
    job: "Media",
    id: 3333,
  },{
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    id: 2222,
  },{
    firstName: "Mikey",
    lastName: "Jordan",
    job: "Not An Employee",
  }];

  function ifUnd (item) {
    var isUnd = item === undefined ? "" : item
    return isUnd
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Employee List!</h1>
      {people.map(p => (
        <>
        <h2>
          {ifUnd(p.firstName) + " " + ifUnd(p.lastName)}
        </h2>
        <h3>{ifUnd(p.job)}</h3>
        <h4>{ifUnd(p.id)}</h4>
        <h2>---------------</h2>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a react question, it's a **javascript** question.

You can check using the `in` operator

```
render() {
  return (
   <div>
   "firstName" in obj && "lastName" in obj &&
      <p>
        {obj.firstName} - {obj.lastName}
      </p>
   </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of them have the same printing pattern, you can try to loop through keys for value check before adding to JSX

```
render() {
  return (
   <div>
   {Object.keys(obj).map((objKey) => obj[objKey] ? <p>{obj[key]}</p> : null)}
   </div>
   );
}
```

For `{obj.firstName} - {obj.lastName}`, you can add getter to `obj` (as your previous question)

```
obj = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  job      :null
  id       : 5566,
  get name() {
     //if one of firstName and lastName is not available, return an empty value as no name
     if(!this.firstName || !this.lastName) {
         return ''
     }
     return `${this.firstName} - ${this.lastName}`
  }
};
```

`Object.keys` will go through `name` for you as well, so you can re-use the same above `map`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `omitBy` from [lodash](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-omitby-method/), this function receives a callback to return a new object, so you can do the following:

```
const objWithoutUndefinedValues = _.omitBy(
  obj,
  // isNil checks for undefined or null values
  _.isNil
)

console.log(objWithoutUndefinedValues)
// {
//  firstName: "John",
//  lastName: "Doe",
//  id: 5566
// }
```

So you can render it in a much more simple way:

```
render() {
  return (
   <div>
   <p>{obj.firstName} - {obj.lastName}</p> 
   </div>
  );
}
```

See the [complete example](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-tamas-vi9437).